# Отсортировать список словарей по значению?

Tags: python, сортировка

У меня есть список словарей такого вида:

```
[
    {'№': '1', 'naimenovanie': 'Pelmeni', 'kolvo': '500', 'vremya': '12:55', 'zamena': '14:11', 'ost': '123'},
    {'№': '2', 'naimenovanie': 'Adrenalin', 'kolvo': '450', 'vremya': '14:55', 'zamena': '11:11', 'ost': '100'}
]
```

Мне нужно отсортировать его по naimenovanie(то есть чтобы Adrenalin был сверху). Подскажите, как это реализовать на питоне?
Конечный ответ должен быть таким

```
[
    {'№': '2', 'naimenovanie': 'Adrenalin', 'kolvo': '450', 'vremya': '14:55', 'zamena': '11:11', 'ost': '100'},
    {'№': '1', 'naimenovanie': 'Pelmeni', 'kolvo': '500', 'vremya': '12:55', 'zamena': '14:11', 'ost': '123'}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вроде бы простая сотрировка тут поможет:

```py
items = [
    {'№': '1', 'naimenovanie': 'Pelmeni', 'kolvo': '500', 'vremya': '12:55', 'zamena': '14:11', 'ost': '123'},
    {'№': '2', 'naimenovanie': 'Adrenalin', 'kolvo': '450', 'vremya': '14:55', 'zamena': '11:11', 'ost': '100'}
];
    
ordered = sorted(items, key=lambda v: v['naimenovanie']) 

print(ordered)
```

Comment: поправил разметку - у вас уехал принт. И не совсем понял, зачем здесь точки с запятыми

Comment: Это отголоски php)

Answer (score 2):

```
from operator import itemgetter
rows.sort(key=itemgetter('naimenovanie'))
```

Answer (score 1):

В коде не заметил ошибку, на самом деле тут всё слишком элементарно

```
data.sort(key=lambda item: item["naimenovanie"])
```